# Get Overall Time duration from this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1896b/2)
This my table same like that in demo, i use the same query as same in that . I need to get overall total duration for all particular employee... I tried a lot..

```
    select
       id, cast(time_stamp as date) [date]
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then time_stamp end),'HH:mm') check_in_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then next_timestamp end),'HH:mm') check_out_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then 
           dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0)
           end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then time_stamp end),'HH:mm') check_in_2
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then next_timestamp end),'HH:mm') check_out_2
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then
           dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0)
           end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_2
from (
      select
            id, time_stamp, AccessType, next_timestamp, next_accesstype
          , dense_rank() over(partition by id, cast(time_stamp as date) order by time_stamp) in_rank
      from table1 t1
      outer apply (
          select top(1) t2.time_stamp, t2.AccessType
          from table1 t2
          where t1.id = t2.id and t1.AccessType <> t2.AccessType
          and cast(t1.time_stamp as date) = cast(t2.time_stamp as date)
          and t1.time_stamp < t2.time_stamp
          order by t2.time_stamp
          ) oa (next_timestamp, next_accesstype)
      where AccessType = 0
     ) d
group by id, cast(time_stamp as date)
```

Expected Output:

```
id  date    check_in_1  check_out_1 total_hrs_1 check_in_2  check_out_2 total_hrs_2  Grand Total
1001    2017-09-05      09:35       12:00       02:25     09:36     12:00       02:24     4:49
1002    2017-09-05      11:00       12:25       01:25     14:00     18:00       04:00     5:25
```

Anyone kindly help me to get this.. i tried a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a good start when asking questions like this.

Comment: i stuck here bro..

Comment: the sample data and the query no longer work together well, the dense_rank() returns ranks > 2 so not all logins/logouts are being displayed

Comment: all output get but last overall duration only not able to get

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data in the SQL Demo I've amended your query like so - see comments in code

```
--I'm using a CTE only because to avoid the messy looking way of calculating the Grand total otherwise
;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT
           id, cast(time_stamp as date) [date]
         , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then time_stamp end),'HH:mm') check_in_1
         , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then next_timestamp end),'HH:mm') check_out_1
         , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then 
               dateadd(SECOND,datediff(SECOND,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0)
               end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_1
         , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then time_stamp end),'HH:mm') check_in_2
         , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then next_timestamp end),'HH:mm') check_out_2
         , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then
               dateadd(SECOND,datediff(SECOND,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0)
               end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_2
         --additional two rows here to represent the number of second between checkin and checkout
         , Total_hrs_1_secs = MAX(case when in_rank = 1 then 
               datediff(SECOND,time_stamp,next_timestamp)  end)
        , Total_hrs_2_secs = MAX(case when in_rank = 2 then
               datediff(SECOND,time_stamp,next_timestamp)  end)
    from (
          select
                id, time_stamp, AccessType, next_timestamp, next_accesstype
              , dense_rank() over(partition by id, cast(time_stamp as date) order by time_stamp) in_rank
          from table1 t1
          outer apply (
              select top(1) t2.time_stamp, t2.AccessType
              from table1 t2
              where t1.id = t2.id and t1.AccessType <> t2.AccessType
              and cast(t1.time_stamp as date) = cast(t2.time_stamp as date)
              and t1.time_stamp < t2.time_stamp
              order by t2.time_stamp
              ) oa (next_timestamp, next_accesstype)
          where AccessType = 0
         ) d
    group by id, cast(time_stamp as date)
)
SELECT X.id
     , X.date
     , X.check_in_1
     , X.check_out_1
     , X.total_hrs_1
     , X.check_in_2
     , X.check_out_2
     , X.total_hrs_2
      --show the Grant total using the seconds rows from above
     , GrandTotal = CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(SECOND,(X.Total_hrs_1_secs + X.Total_hrs_2_secs),0),108) 
FROM cteX X
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have more than 2 pairs of login/logout on a single day, so an "in_row" is calculated to output the extra logins/logouts;

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a8ff/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([id] int, [time_stamp] datetime, [AccessType] varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([id], [time_stamp], [AccessType])
VALUES
    (1001, '2017-09-05 09:35:00', 0),
    (1001, '2017-09-05 09:36:00', 0),
     (1001, '2017-09-05 09:37:00', 0),
    (1002, '2017-09-05 11:00:00', 0),
    (1001, '2017-09-05 12:00:00', 1),
    (1002, '2017-09-05 12:25:00', 1),
    (1001, '2017-09-05 13:00:00', 0),
    (1002, '2017-09-05 14:00:00', 0),
    (1001, '2017-09-05 17:00:00', 1),
    (1002, '2017-09-05 18:00:00', 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
       id, in_row, cast(time_stamp as date) [date]
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then time_stamp end),'HH:mm') check_in_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then next_timestamp end),'HH:mm') check_out_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then 
           dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0)
           end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 0 then time_stamp end),'HH:mm') check_in_2
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 0 then next_timestamp end),'HH:mm') check_out_2
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 0 then
           dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0)
           end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_2
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 0 then
           dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0)
           end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_2
     , format(dateadd(ss,sum(secs_diff),0),'HH:mm') total_hrs
from (
      select
            id, time_stamp, AccessType, next_timestamp, next_accesstype
          , datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp) secs_diff 
          , dense_rank() over(partition by id, cast(time_stamp as date) order by time_stamp) % 2 in_rank
          , (count(*) over(partition by id, cast(time_stamp as date) order by time_stamp) + 1) / 2 in_row
      from table1 t1
      outer apply (
          select top(1) t2.time_stamp, t2.AccessType
          from table1 t2
          where t1.id = t2.id and t1.AccessType <> t2.AccessType
          and cast(t1.time_stamp as date) = cast(t2.time_stamp as date)
          and t1.time_stamp < t2.time_stamp
          order by t2.time_stamp
          ) oa (next_timestamp, next_accesstype)
      where AccessType = 0
     ) d
group by id, in_row, cast(time_stamp as date)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a8ff/1/0)**:

```
|   id | in_row |       date | check_in_1 | check_out_1 | total_hrs_1 | check_in_2 | check_out_2 | total_hrs_2 | total_hrs_2 | total_hrs |
|------|--------|------------|------------|-------------|-------------|------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-----------|
| 1001 |      1 | 2017-09-05 |      09:35 |       12:00 |       02:25 |      09:36 |       12:00 |       02:24 |       02:24 |     04:49 |
| 1001 |      2 | 2017-09-05 |      09:37 |       12:00 |       02:23 |      13:00 |       17:00 |       04:00 |       04:00 |     06:23 |
| 1002 |      1 | 2017-09-05 |      11:00 |       12:25 |       01:25 |      14:00 |       18:00 |       04:00 |       04:00 |     05:25 |
```

Comment: thanks bro.. but my expected result mentioned above not same like this..

Comment: sure it isn't but your sample data (as I mentioned already) has **more than 2 login/logouts for one person on one day** So if you want your query to ignore data go ahead, or you could have your query display the problems so that something can be done about it. Your choice.

Comment: you could just add "where in_row = 1" and the extra data would be hidden just like you asked for.... but think about that before you do it

Comment: can i get name of date in this query?

Comment: Name of date is just formatting. Make use of documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

Comment: userColumn 'A.Dayss' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Add a.dayass into the group by clause. (That's what the error message tells you.)

Answer (score 0):

This gives u exact result mentioned above:

```
 select
       id, cast(time_stamp as date) [date]
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then time_stamp end),'HH:mm') check_in_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then next_timestamp end),'HH:mm') check_out_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then 
           dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0)
           end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then time_stamp end),'HH:mm') check_in_2
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then next_timestamp end),'HH:mm') check_out_2
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then
           dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0)
           end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_2
  , format(dateadd(ss,sum(secs_diff),0),'HH:mm') Total_Hrs
from (
      select
            id, time_stamp, AccessType, next_timestamp, next_accesstype, datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp) secs_diff 
          , dense_rank() over(partition by id, cast(time_stamp as date) order by time_stamp) in_rank
      from table1 t1
      outer apply (
          select top(1) t2.time_stamp, t2.AccessType
          from table1 t2
          where t1.id = t2.id and t1.AccessType <> t2.AccessType
          and cast(t1.time_stamp as date) = cast(t2.time_stamp as date)
          and t1.time_stamp < t2.time_stamp
          order by t2.time_stamp
          ) oa (next_timestamp, next_accesstype)
      where AccessType = 0
     ) d
group by id, cast(time_stamp as date)
```